# Git merge but rewrite everything

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Let's say that I have a branch called `test`, and a branch called `master`. Is it possible to do a `git merge` to make the master branch have the changes from `test`, but rewrite the entire file?

As far as I know, merge tries to make a file that incorporates both branches. Is it possible to make a file (let's say `index.html`) on the master branch be exactly the same as the one on the `test` branch after a merge?

Comment: you are supposing that all changes from master are of no interest

Comment: @jo_ I would create a branch of master first called `master-old` or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*rename master to something else*

> git checkout master
>
> git checkout -b master_old

*change your dev branch into master*

> git checkout dev_branch
>
> git branch -f master

then once you tested you can clean up useless branches :)

> git branch -d dev_branch

watch out before deleting master_old , some colleagues might have some work in there

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout a file from another branch and commit it to master, instead of doing a merge:

```
git checkout master              # Make sure you are on master
git checkout test -- index.html  # Get the file from test branch
git commit                       # Commit the file and write a nice message
```

so you can clearly see what you changed from the `master` version, and you don't need to make a `master-old`.

Comment: But what if I want to preserve the commit histories of both branches? In this scenario the branches are two completely different strategies that I have been developing in parallel.

Comment: Then how about doing a normal merge, and then do this checkout?

Comment: But will that leave bits from both codes in my final document?